# Debian hybrid graphics card - Can't make Radeon work

Tags: debian, graphics, amd, hybrid-graphics

Quite new to Linux world, but love it and have been using Debian for daily use since the install.

However my problem is with the graphics card. I have a Lenovo v310, hybrid graphics card of intel hd graphics 620 and AMD Radeon R5 M430.
However I could not find any way to install and choose Radeon graphics card. Linux environment is different in sense of drivers, and I am really lost for where to find the right drivers for Radeon R5 M430.